# Accessing audio samples from linphone

Tags: linux, audio, sampling

I'm using linphonec (without gtk interface, only command line) in Linux and I want to access incoming and outgoing sound samples, but I don't know what file should I edit to access them.
Can anybody give me a clue, please?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the outgoing and incoming sound samples are related to a call
e.g. you are typing `linphonec> call sip:usernumber@someproxy.net`.

The call stack of the function is:

```
lpc_cmd_call from linphone-version/console/commands.c
linphone_core_invite_with_params from linphone-version/coreapi/linphonecore.c
linphone_core_invite_address_with_params from linphone-version/coreapi/linphonecore.c
linphone_core_start_invite from linphone-version/coreapi/linphonecore.c
linphone_call_init_media_streams from linphone-version/coreapi/linphonecall.c
audio_stream_new from from linphone-version/mediastreamer2/src/audiostream.c
```

Media stream is initialised on the host and can be accessed using mediastreamer2 API

In terms of accepting a call see the following call stack:

```
linphone_core_accept_call from linphone-version/coreapi/linphonecore.c
linphone_core_update_streams from linphone-version/coreapi/callbacks.c
linphone_call_start_media_streams from  linphone-version/coreapi/linphonecall.c
linphone_call_start_audio_stream from  linphone-version/coreapi/linphonecall.c
audio_stream_start_full from linphone-version/mediastreamer2/src/audiostream.c
```

Media stream is initialised on the client and can be accessed using mediastreamer2 API.

mediastreamer2 API documentation is avaliable [here](http://download-mirror.savannah.gnu.org/releases/linphone/mediastreamer/doc/modules.html)

linphone Source Code is avaliable [here](http://linphone.sourcearchive.com/documentation/3.5.0-1/files.html) or 
[here](http://fossies.org/unix/privaat/linphone-3.5.0.tar.gz/dox/index.html)